# Django Signals stops listening after about 2 calls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-signals

So I have the following signal set up

```
    post_save.connect(self.increment_on,
                      sender=self.model_dict[self.model_involved],
                      dispatch_uid='increment_for' +
                                   self.model_involved + '_creation')
```

The signal works for the first 1-3 saves of the model and then stops running the function ( `increment_on` )

Is this normal? I am combing through the docs on signals and cant find it. post_save is wrapped in a function, should I call that function again? if so where?

Comment: From the source code ...

>    def disconnect(self, receiver=None, sender=None, weak=None, dispatch_uid=None):
        """
        Disconnect receiver from sender for signal.

        If weak references are used, disconnect need not be called. The receiver
        will be remove from dispatch automatically.


So now how to clear this.....

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I thought I read somewhere weak should not be set to false on the connect method, but everything works as expected when thats exactly what I do

```
    post_save.connect(self.increment_on,
                      sender=self.model_dict[self.model_involved],
                      dispatch_uid='increment_for' +
                                   self.model_involved + '_creation',
                      weak=False)
```